# How to add UI component on button click in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]I want to add one more Text or TextField (UI Component) to the screen on clicking any button.

My Code:

```
Button(action: { 

        Text("Adding Text after button clicked") 
        .font(.largeTitle) .fontWeight(.light) 
        .foregroundColor(Color.green) 

}) { Text("Add Text") }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't add it as a comment! Put it in your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add random UI based on click of `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isAddUI: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Hello..").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.bold)

            if isAddUI {
                Text("Adding Text after button clicked")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.isAddUI = true
            }) { Text("Add Text") }
        }
    }
}
```